# If $f(x)<g(x)$ prove or disprove that $\lim f(x)<\lim g(x)$

Tags: limits, inequality, epsilon-delta

Please read the question before you downvote or report as duplicate.

I saw 2 similar instances of this question but I feel that the answers in those questions are incorrect for my question. I don't have enough reputation to comment on those questions so I had to make a new question.

So this is my question:

> Let $I$ be an open interval and let $a \in I$. Suppose $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = M$
>
> Prove or disprove : $f(x) < g(x)$,  $\forall x \in I$ $\implies$ $L<M$

All the answers on this site says that the above proposition is false and that $L \le M$.

And they've used construction proofs to show that there $\exists$ $f(x) < g(x)$ such that $L = M$.

But I think the above proposition is true because all the answers on this site ignore the 2 facts,  $\forall x \in I$, $f(x) < g(x)$ and $a \in I$.

They've used instances where either $a \notin I$ or instances where $f(x) = g(x)$.

Some of them has used instances where $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \infty$.

But doesn't  $\forall x \in I$, $f(x) < g(x)$ imply that this inequality hold for all $x$ values in $I$ and that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be real numbers.(Not $\infty$)

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ continuous, or are they just required to have a limit at $a$?

Comment: If you don't care about $f$ and $g$ being continuous, consider as an example $f(x)=\begin{cases}-1&\text{if}~x=0\\x^4&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=x^2$.  Here $f(x)<g(x)$ for every $x\in(-1,1)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$

Comment: If you require $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be continuous over the interval and you require $a$ to be in the interval, then by definition of continuity one has $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)<g(a)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ and so $L<M$ as you expect.  The point of the exercise though is likely that the conditions that $f$ and $g$ are continuous is *not* given as a hypothesis in the questions you saw elsewhere on the site and that you shouldn't let what you know about continuous functions cloud your judgement for when the functions are allowed to get more exotic.

Comment: it's certainly $L \le M$ ...

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks. Now I get it. And yes the question doesn't say anything about continuity of the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not $a \in I$ is irrelevant: the value of $L = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ does not depend on $f(a)$ and $M = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ does not depend on $g(a)$. So, in case $a \in I$, the fact that $f(a) < g(a)$ does tell you nothing at all about about the relation between $L$ and $M$.

For example: take $f(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = -1$ and take $g(x) = x^2$. Then $f(x) < g(x)$ for *all* $x$, even for $x = 0$ because I've given $f(0)$ a special value. Still $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0$.

If you assume $a \in I$ and assume $f$ and $g$ to be *continuous*, then of course $L = f(a)$ and $M = g(a)$. The condition $\forall x \in I: f(x) < g(x)$, then gives $f(a) < g(a)$, so $L < M$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $I=(-1,1)$

$f(x)=x $ for $x<0$, $f(x)=-x$ for $x>0$, $f(0)=-1$

$g(x)=0.5x$ for $x<0$, $g(x)=-0.5x$ for $x>0$, $g(0)=1$

Then, $g>f$ and the limits at 0 are both 0.